# How to set the default Styler for a pandas DataFrame's _repr_html method?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, pandas-styles

I've got a pandas DataFrame with a column that's a url, and I've written the following formatter to present it in my notebook as a link:

```py
def make_clickable(val):
    # target _blank to open new window
    return '<a target="_blank" href="{}">{}</a>'.format(val, val)
all_data.style.format({'url': make_clickable})
```

This nicely prints out my table with the urls made clickable, but what I'd *really* like to do is to make this style persist as the default for that frame, so that it's used for the `_repr_html` of my dataframe (and slices of it) throughout the same notebook.

Does anyone know if that's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it's not possible to register a default style. We overrode [`_repr_html_`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/c23649143781c658f792e8f7a5b4368ed01f719c/pandas/core/frame.py#L722) instead, replacing `clickable_urls` argument.

```
            table_id=None,
            render_links=render_links,
        )
```

https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/c23649143781c658f792e8f7a5b4368ed01f719c/pandas/core/frame.py